# Windows Service not starting on cold boot

Tags: .net, windows, visual-c++, windows-services

Windows isn't ALWAYS starting my service on a cold boot, most of the time it does, but every now and again it fails to start with a 'Timeout was reached' error in the system log.

I added a line to dump the time at the very start of the service to see what is going on.

After about 15 shutdowns and restarts, my service finally didn't start.

Looking in the application event log, I see the Windows License Validated event at 8:18:29 and WMI started at 8:19:04
but when I look at my log file I see 
    '08:15:21: _tmain'

Which means my service didn't even get loaded on this reboot, or at least the 'main' didn't get called.

Looking at the system event log: 
I see at 8:18:57 an Event 7009: A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the XXXX service to connect.

In the registry at 'HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control' I have the value 'ServicesPipeTimeout' set to 90000

My service executable is C++ with /clr support based on .Net 2.0
the executable also is NOT signed and I've added

```
<generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
```

to the .config file, just to be sure.

The service is dependent on the Event Log, which is obviously working.

This is Windows 7 x64 VM with 4GB of memory and little else but does seem to thrash on start up and have trouble getting a network connection.

If I start the service manually, it starts within 5 seconds.

I don't want to make the service 'Automatic (Delayed Start) since that happens 2 minutes after Windows has started.

I have no idea what to try next or even where to look.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

thank you.

[EDIT]
Here's the entry of my code.  Note that I'm writing to the log BEFORE I do anything with the service, which is all inside the MyService class.

```
int _tmain(int /*argc*/, TCHAR* /*argv*/[], TCHAR* /*envp*/[])
{
 SaveStringToFile(L"C:\\start.txt",  CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%H:%M:%S") + L": _tmain\n");
 SetUnhandledExceptionFilter( MyCustomFilter ); 
 OutputDebugString(_T(__FUNCTION__));
 CMyService Service;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a race condition during start up.  If the Event Log has not started working before the system attempts to start your service, and there is a dependency on that log, this may cause your service to fail.

Perhaps you can ***[Change the order in which your service application is started with respect to the Log](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-change-startup-order-services)***.

***EDIT*** to add information from comments

In my experience, there is a real danger failing to launch a service executable if too much is done during initialization.  I put only the essentials in.  In this case, write to a log: (also included snippets of main and ServiceMain() to illustrate the exception logging I referred to earlier...)

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
//  
//  InitService(void)  - Service initialization
//
//  Caution - limit what is done from this function.
//  The service start function: SVC_ServiceStart()
//  is limited in how much time can be allocated  
//  to start this executable before it times out.   
//  
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
int InitService(void)
{
    char buf[200];

    sprintf(buf, "Monitoring started");
    if(LOG_STRTSTOP==1)WriteToLog(buf);

    return SVC_SUCCESS;
}
```

***Where*** my main() and ServiceMain() look like this:

```
void main()
{
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[2];
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceName = "xyzMon";
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain;

    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceName = NULL;
    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceProc = NULL;
    // Start the control dispatcher thread for our service
    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable);
    LogProgramFlow("Leaving main()");
}

void ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int error, result;

    pS = &s;

    ServiceStatus.dwServiceType             = SERVICE_WIN32;
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState            = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted        = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
    ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode           = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint              = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint                = 3000;


    hStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler( "xyzMon", (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION)ControlHandler);
    if (hStatus == (SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE)0)
    {
        // Registering Control Handler failed
        if(LOG_ERR==1) WriteToLog("Registering Control Handler failed");

        return;
    }
    // Initialize Service
    error = InitService();
    ....
```

Comment: I'll check that, but since I'm seeing event log entries a full minute before the timeout event for my service I don't think it's a race with the Event Log.  Still I might be able to move my service to the very last loaded service group...it's a hack but it might work.

Comment: I have had to re-order a service created to provide monitoring, and depended on other services to work (5 of them).  Given you have verified it is likely not the EventLog, there may be other dependencies you are not yet aware of.  You might also scrub the internals of your service executable to make sure that anything in the initialization sections (before it enters the service loop) can either start promptly, or make an entry to a log file (one besides the syslog you referred to), with message(s) specific to the nature of the failure.  I am curious, what value are you using for timeout?

Comment: hmmm.....I'm the ServicesPipeTimeout is set to 90 seconds but it doesn't appear to be used.  I'll do a depends on it and see if there is anything (which I don't think there is) other than standard libraries.

Comment: I was not referring to library (.dll) dependencies rather things in your executable's initialization section that may take indeterminate durations of time to start up, or perhaps may even fail.  This could result in your service executable not even making it into ServiceMain().  (depending on how you have architected the executable)  See edit for additional information.  (too much to put here)

Comment: I added a bit of my void main() my post.  I'm writing to the log before the ServiceTable or anything else gets involved.  I suppose it could be some static variable somewhere that's failing.  I'm going to start with event classes and maybe a process monitor to record startup would shed some light on what is going on.

Comment: I walked thru the event log for both a successful start and a failed start and the other services that had started before mine on the successful pass were: VMWare Tools, Distributed Link Tracking Client and Superfetch.    I suppose it's time for me to research what those do.

Comment: I think I MIGHT have stumbled onto the problem, or at least one of them.  It appears that the product configuration settings code had be moved to a .NET class library and the construction of the service needed one of those settings, so....the JIT was getting involved BEFORE I could tell the SCM that I needed more time.  I'm still not sure why logging in main() wasn't always being created.  Anyway, I moved the .Net code out of the constructor and 8 cold reboots later, it's still starting....  Thank you Ryyker for being my sounding board and getting me there.

Comment: #10 test failed and it failed to write anything to my log files.  Looks like there's another problem.

Comment: re: sounding board, your welcome.  It is good seeing other aspects of service issues.  They are never boring to code and debug.  How soon into the service code are you logging anything?  i.e. during debug, I place calls to logging functions as soon as I enter main, then into serviceMain, and follow into each called function. A kind of execution trace log.  If service fails to start, then the log shows where (approximately) in the code the problem exists.   Side note, I have never used a VMWare product that was very fast.  If their tools services are typical VMWare, they may start slow.

Comment: I wrote a routine that dumps a string to a file, then I made a static class that calls it in the constructor, so that would catch the 'Before' the main is call, and then called the same routine in main() and in service main.  I can't really blame this on VMWare since my wife's computer failed to start the service too...once.

Comment: Have you tried setting your service to Automatic (Delayed Start) just to see if its starting performance is better?  It so, then the problem would point to some service dependance that you were not aware of.  (If any of the library calls in your service depend on another running service, then that service has to be started).  If not, it points to your service application. Something like a tight wait loop, or a blocking function call.  Anything that would cause Windows to perceive a threat to smooth operation, and shut it down.

Comment: I looked through our expansive comment trail and may have missed it, but have you tried re-ordering your services?  (see link early in my post)  changing the start order is a good approach to dealing with any service dependencies you may have, especially since you have identified some that start slowly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79705/discussion-between-iunknown-and-ryyker).

Comment: I am blocked from using this chat location by my domain policies.  Sorry

Comment: opps...sorry for moving it to a chat.  I've been unable to track it down with ProcessMonitor either. What I'm trying now is to make my own Service Group and add it to the end of ServiceLoadGroup.

Comment: I couldn't get the load group thing to work, but by marking it as AutoStart -Delay, I got 140 successful starts after rebooting.  I'm going to try getting Microsoft involved.

Comment: Autostart (delay) working suggests a strong possibility the problem lays in a prerequisite service.  If Microsoft is not able to help, then try trial and error.  Place your service as the last possible service to start (and remove the delay).  if it starts regularly, move it up (perhaps in sections of 4 or 5 to speed the process) each time to see when it breaks.  Using this brute force method may expose the prerequisite service.  Seems overly complicated, but given you have tried everything else, this is all I can thing of.

Comment: I tend to agree but 'How' does Windows know I need a dependent service without running any of my code?  I do use the WTSAPI, but so those APIs will just fail if the service hasn't been started.

Comment: I cannot speak to your service code specifically as I do not know all the details, but a recent service of mine depended on 5 other services, (custom domain controller, time time tracker, etc) before it could successfully load.  I was forced into using the delayed start because of this.  Point is, I did not figure this out until I noticed that my service always started first time on a pre-booted PC, ...

Comment: ...but never on a freshly booted PC (from cold start).  I did a little reading on the utilities I was using, and learned about the prerequisite services from some bulletins by the provider of the libraries I was using.  In your case, delayed start is not desirable, so you are constrained to find an order of service precedence that will work for you.

Comment: "Before it would Load" as in the main() wouldn't be called?  I have no problem making the service dependent on a later loading service, if I knew of one that every window box had running.

Comment: Alluding to the fact that if I did not specify a delayed start, it would attempt to start before one of its prerequisite services finished initializing, and would fail because something it required (usually a domain related item) was not available.  Windows will delay the start, i.e. not even load the executable for 2 minutes if the delayed start option is set.  This was what worked in my case.

Comment: at least 300 reboots later with various configurations (thank you VMWare) if there is enough memory,  (> 4GB) it never fails to start.  I'm going do drop the RAM down to 2GB and add a dependence on the Workstation service.  I THINK the Workstation service is a required service for all versions of Windows.

Comment: I made the service dependent on Workstations and ran reboot testing overnight.  On a Windows Home 7, 1 GB Single Core VM - UAC On - dependent on Workstation

Marked as Automatic, 161 reboots, 131 starts, 30 failures